# Minimum value of a sum of logarithms

Tags: summation, logarithms

Find the minimum sum value:

$$\log_{x_1}\bigl(x_2 - \tfrac{1}{4}\bigr)+\log_{x_2}\bigl(x_3 - \tfrac{1}{4}\bigr)+\dots+\log_{x_{n-1}}\bigl(x_n - \tfrac{1}{4}\bigr)+\log_{x_n}\bigl(x_1 - \tfrac{1}{4}\bigr)$$

With $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ belonging to the range (1, 1/4)

My attempt:

I saw a solution in this forum that used inequality of rearrangements so that it will be a sum of general term:

$$\frac{\log\bigl(x_i-\frac{1}{4}\bigr)}{\log x_i}$$

From this, the solution stated that the minimum value is 2. I could not understand how it reached that value.

Comment: Is the domain of $x_i$, $(1/4,1)$ or $(1,5/4)$?

Comment: I wonder if they do not mean $\frac{\log\bigl(x_i-\frac{1}{4}\bigr)}{\log x_j}$